# Open new tab with chrome extension an inject css with jQuery

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I use a chrome extension with a popup to inject a website and hide some divs.

1. The problem now is, I want to open a new tab with the
   url: https://app.example.de/dashboard/ and inject the style with my contentscript.js
2. Another problem is: Sometimes the application reloads the page. After this, all injections are lost. Is there any chance to inject allways the https://app.example.de/dashboard/ without click on the popup.html-Button?

The following code works fine, if the page is already open.

**manifest.json**

```
{
"name": "example stealth mode",
"version": "1.1",
"description": "lorem ipsum",
  "browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "icon-on.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
  "default_title": "example stealth mode"

},
"manifest_version": 2,
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*.app.example.de/*"],
      "js": ["jquery-1.11.0.min.js", "background.js"]
    }
  ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs", "https://*.app.example.de/*"
    ]   
}
```

**popup.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById('On').addEventListener('click', clickHandlerOn);
})
// An
function clickHandlerOn(e) {
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({directive: "popup-click"}, function(response) {
        this.close(); // close the popup when the background finishes processing request
    });
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        switch (request.directive) {
        case "popup-click":
            // execute the content script
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { // defaults to the current tab

                file: "contentscript.js", // script to inject into page and run in sandbox
                allFrames: true // This injects script into iframes in the page and doesn't work before 4.0.266.0.
            });

            sendResponse({}); // sending back empty response to sender
            break;
        default:
            // helps debug when request directive doesn't match
            alert("Unmatched request of '" + request + "' from script to background.js from " + sender);
        }
    }
);
```

**contenscript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div#hlXXXContent').hide();
    $('#hlYYY').hide();
    $('#hlZZZ').hide();
    $('h3.hlVVV').append(' Stealth Mode');
});
```

**popup.html**

```
<li><button class="hl123" id="On"><span class="hlSubmenuSelected">Stealthmode on</span</button></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filename contentscript.js is odd because it's not a content script as you're using it. Why don't you try experimenting with [`run_at`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) and have something load on each target page load, and that'll be your opportunity for your code to decide whether to do more things to the page.